# PowerShell Windows Installer Com Object

Tags: windows, powershell, installation, comobject

I'm trying to modify the contents of an MSI file using Powershell.  To do so I create an instance of a WindowsInstaller.Installer then use $installer.OpenDatabase and $database.OpenView.  Similar functionality works in VBScript and I've seen samples on-line that appear to work.

```
$installer = new-object -comobject "WindowsInstaller.Installer"
$database = $installer.OpenDatabase("C:\Temp\Setup.msi", 1)
```

For the above code, I get an error "Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] doesn't contain a method named 'OpenDatabase'."

```
$installer = new-object -comobject "WindowsInstaller.Installer"
$database = $installer.InvokeMethod("OpenDatabase","C:\Temp\Setup.msi", 1)
```

If I attempt to use $installer.InvokeMethod I get the same error "Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] doesn't contain a method named 'InvokeMethod'."

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [this](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/12743-windows-installer-automation-interface-problems-powershell.html) thread for some guidance. Basically the MSI COM object is implemented in a way that confuses PS. There is a link to a blog post discussing it in that thread.

Comment: The blog post linked to from that page appears to be gone (the Windows Live space doesn't exist, error page says).  Does anyone remember what it said for a workaround?

Comment: Sorry to answer my own question.  It looks like at least one of the workarounds is implemented here:
http://www.snowland.se/2010/02/21/read-msi-information-with-powershell/

Answer (score 2):

The originally accepted answer link, is no longer valid.

In the comments, JohnB has posted a link that has a great example of how to use the Windows Installer from Powershell.

There's also a CodePlex project that wraps a lot functionality and could be useful:
[Windows Installer PowerShell Module](http://psmsi.codeplex.com/)