# powershell com object windows installer

Tags: powershell, com

I would like to leverage the following

`$wi=new-object -com WindowsInstaller.Installer`

If I do a `$wi |gm` I do not see the method I want *"Products"*.
I would like to iterate *Products* and show a list of all items installed on the system.

So I thought... let me do a `$wi.gettype().invokemember`

Not really sure what to do `$wi.gettype().invokemember("Products","InvokeMethod")`
or something yields cannot find an overload...

But now I am lost.  I have looked elsewhere but I don't want to create a whole XML file.  I should be able to access the com objects methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are trying to get a list of installed programs in Windows, there is a native Powershell way, which is actually using WMI behind the scenes:

   ```
   Get-WmiObject Win32_Product
   ```

   Here's a related article from [Microsoft Scripting Guys](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/11/13/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software.aspx).

   It appears that this approach [has some issues](http://sdmsoftware.com/wmi/why-win32_product-is-bad-news/), so better be avoided.

   > When you query this class, the way the provider works is that it
   >   actually performs a Windows Installer “reconfiguration” on every MSI
   >   package on the system as its performing the query!
2. I tried my best to find a solution that involves WindowsInstaller com object, but all of them point to [an article that no longer exists](http://abhishek225.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!13469C7B7CE6E911!165.entry). Here is [one on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450953/powershell-windows-installer-com-object).
3. An alternative solution is to give a try to [psmsi on CodePlex](http://psmsi.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&ProjectName=psmsi).

Comment: win32_product is plagued with issues, like query forces a package reconcilation.

Comment: @rismoney: you are right, I did a research and updated the answer with another option. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here my code-snippet for this:

```
cls
$msi = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
$prodList = foreach ($p in $msi.Products()) {
    try {
        $name = $msi.ProductInfo($p, 'ProductName')
        $ver  = $msi.ProductInfo($p, 'VersionString')
        $guid = $p
        [tuple]::Create($name, $ver, $guid)
    } catch {}
}
$prodlist
```